# How to change Textmate's context menu key binding?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

In Textmate there is a great shortcut to get to the context menu without using the mouse (I wish it worked systemwide!!!). It is Opt+F2.

When working on my Macbook, however, F2 is mapped to screen brightness, so I have to press fn+opt+F2, for which I have to use both hands - and that's quite uncomfortable.
Is the a way how I could map it to the right opt key, for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For TextMate 2 you can create `~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/KeyBindings.dict` and let it contain something like:

```
{ "@d" = "showContextMenu:"; }
```

Here `@d` corresponds to <kbd>⌘D</kbd>. See this [blog post on how to construct the key equivalent strings](http://blog.macromates.com/2005/key-bindings-for-switchers/).

Source: [TextMate mailing list](http://lists.macromates.com/textmate/2013-August/036472.html)

Key binding files are read in the following order. A new binding for a bound key overrides the previous one:

1. `/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Resources/StandardKeyBinding.dict`
2. `/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`
3. `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`
4. `/path/to/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/KeyBindings.dict`
5. `~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/KeyBindings.dict`

A relaunch of TextMate (<kbd>⌃⌘Q</kbd>) is required before changes take effect.

Comment: Had to put this in ~/Library/KeyBindings, then it would work for me. Thanks!

Comment: Should also work when put in `~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/KeyBindings.dict` (for TextMate 2). I have updated the answer to list all locations searched.